# Can't setup Google map v2

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying over a week to setup my Google Map v2. but its not working for me.I tried answers from questions related to it but no use.i couldn't track the exact problem.please help.
Here is my xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
<fragment 
  android:id="@+id/map"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

In my map.class I have

```
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.*;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;  
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Map extends Activity {

    private GoogleMap googleMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.map);
        if (googleMap == null) {
            googleMap = ((MapFragment)     getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.map)).getMap();

            // check if map is created successfully or not
            if (googleMap == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            }
        }

    }
    }
```

My API key is correct and I imported google play services library as per the directions.In my manifest file

```
<permission
        android:name="com.example.sellatease.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.sellatease.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

       <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="21"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

         <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />
```

and

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
     <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyCwHLxfMRBnD_MJDQDV9IYBZTxbkCVlZsA" />
```

[This is my error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtYux.png)

And in console I got can not find googleplayserviceslib.apk error too.

[new error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DFaq.png)

Answer (score 2):

you need to extend **FragmentActivity/AppCompatActivity** if you are using **SupportMapFragment**.

> public class Map extends FragmentActivity/AppCompatActivity {

**And**

```
   FragmentManager myFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
   SupportMapFragment mySupportMapFragment  = (SupportMapFragment)myFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
   googleMap = mySupportMapFragment.getMap();
```

You can check **[Android Map V2](http://androidcodeblogspot.blogspot.in/2014/02/android-map-v2-marker-example_19.html)**

Comment: Let me inform please

Comment: @DanielNugent yes yes .

Comment: Unable to instantiate application android.app.application: java.lang.illegalStateException:unable to get package info for com.example.sellatease

Comment: Now I getting the error : error inflating clas fragment. y am getting this error?

Comment: you can check demo http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/

Comment: @Bivin using Android studio or ecllipse ?

Comment: did you change KEY ?

Comment: I just started coding in android.i am using eclipse

Comment: yes .i got the key from developers console.and I enabled google map api too

Comment: Uninstall and run again app

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

Comment: @ Phuoc Huynh  When i tried this I got the following error.Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sellatease/com.example.sellatease.Map}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #4: Error inflating class fragment

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

**activity_map.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <fragment 
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Map.java**

```
public class Map extends android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

  private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {

     if (mMap == null) {

       mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
            .getMap();

       if (mMap != null) {
         setUpMap();
       }
     }
  }
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
 ....
<permission
    android:name="com.example.sellatease.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="21"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<uses-permission 
    android:name="com.example.sellatease.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<!-- Maps API needs OpenGL ES 2.0. -->
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

  <application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >    

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyCwHLxfMRBnD_MJDQDV9IYBZTxbkCVlZsA" />


         <activity
            android:name=".Map"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
        </activity>

   </application>
   ....
```

**UPDATE**

Create Google map programatically.

**activity_map.xml**

```
    <FrameLayout
        android:gravity="top"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/mapContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </FrameLayout>
```

**Map.java**

```
public class Map extends AppCompatActivity{

private GoogleMap mMap;
private SupportMapFragment mMapFragment;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

        mMapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =  getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.mapContainer, mMapFragment, "map");
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        mMapFragment.getMapAsync(mapReadyCallback);
   }

    private OnMapReadyCallback mapReadyCallback = new OnMapReadyCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

        mMap = googleMap;

        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        mMap.setTrafficEnabled(true);
        mMap.setIndoorEnabled(true);
        mMap.setBuildingsEnabled(true);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
    }
};
```

Comment: Whats this setUpMap function includes?

Comment: setUpMap() that describe your map configurations, i.e, zoom controls, map type( normal, hybrid, satellite, terrain )

Comment: when using ur method am getting this error.Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sellatease/com.example.sellatease.Map}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #4: Error inflating class fragment  . this same error occures for so many tries.what to do?

Comment: Did you build your project as Google Api

Comment: I build my project as google api. and i updated the code with new. i couldnt extend appcompact activity due to some error.so I use fragment activity instead.  and I end up with the following errorjava.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/maps/SupportMapFragment;
02-15 15:18:31.241: E/AndroidRuntime(2044): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.sellatease-2/base.apk"]

Comment: am stucking with these problem over a week..i didnt understand why i couldn't set up my map